# Append two dataframes and continue assigning Id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have two dataframes, `old_df` and `df`:

```
 old_df

 Id   col1    col2
 0    Apple   Good
 1    Banana  Good

 df

 col1   col2
 Apple  Normal
 Pear   Good
```

The output I am looking for after appending `old_df` and `df`:

```
new_df

Id   col1   col2
0    Apple  Good
0    Apple  Normal
1    Banana Good
2    Pear   Good
```

The question I am trying to solve is, how to append two dataframes on `col1` on condition: if `old_df` and `df` `col1` values are the same, assign `old_df`’s `Id` to `df`’s. If not, continue `Id`, by creating new `Id` value for `df`’s `col1` value.

Edit:

The tricky part is, I have to continue assigning new id numbers for new entrances and give old id numbers for the existing entrances.

Answer (score 2):

Using `concat` with `sort_values`, then we re-create the Id by using `category`

```
newdf=pd.concat([dfold,df],sort=True).sort_values(['col1','Id'])
newdf.Id=newdf.col1.astype('category').cat.codes
newdf
Out[62]: 
   Id    col1    col2
0   0   Apple    Good
0   0   Apple  Normal
1   1  Banana    Good
1   2    Pear    Good
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The tricky part is, I have to continue assigning new id numbers for new entrances and give old id numbers for the existing entrances.

Answer (score 0):

The data frames can be joined using the `concat` method and sorted using the `sort_values` method.

To provide a complete example, you can use the following code to create the required data frames:

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# create dataframes
old_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0, 'Apple', 'Good'],
    [1, 'Banana', 'Good']],
    columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Apple', 'Normal'],
    ['Pear', 'Good']],
    columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Then, this code will allow you to join the data, create the id column, and sort.

```
# join data frames
new_df = pd.concat([old_df, df])

# create the id field by using astype('category')
new_df.id = new_df.col1.astype('category').cat.codes

 # reorder columns and sort data frame by id
new_df = new_df[['id', 'col1', 'col2']].sort_values(by='id')

# print results
print(new_df.head())
```

The results look like this:

```
   id    col1    col2
0   0   Apple    Good
0   0   Apple  Normal
1   1  Banana    Good
1   2    Pear    Good
```

All of this and many more great examples are covered in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) on merging, joining, and concatenating data frames.